# How to find the entry point in a java web application to debug?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, servlets, web-applications

I am trying to debug a java web application. I have configured tomcat in eclipse, added my application to tomcat and started the tomcat in debugging mode.

Now, when the user performs any action on the web page, the request hits the server, goes through some java/tomcat classes and finally reaches our application code.

If I know which of the application classes/methods will be executed, I can set a breakpoint and start debugging from there. But if I don't know which code will be executed, how can I set breakpoint?

Basically I am trying to figure out which application class/method is executed when user performs an action on the page.

I know I can set a breakpoint in the Servlet doGet/doPost method. But we are using struts and we have many more general servlets also. So it is difficult to set breakpoint in all of them.

Please help.

Comment: how can you debug server side while being client side?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Tomcat logs (or console). You should see which part of code is executed when you are doing something on your web page then set breakpoints. When you finally catch the program somewhere try to find a better place according to stacktrace in your debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your struts-config.xml file and find the action that matches your URL. Most Struts implementations use the *.do pattern to match Struts actions. The path part of the URL without the .do will match an action configuration in your struts-config.xml file. Find the action class that is called and put your breakpoint in the execute() method.